# Mysql - Emoji characters in database

Tags: mysql

I am using emojis in our project. our database had `CHARACTER SET utf8`. But emoji are not saved. The error is:

```
1366 Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x9C\xF0\x9F...'
```

Comment: What `collation` is used for the tables and the specific columns?

Comment: i have used **utf8_general_ci**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. alert database, datatable `CHARSET=utf8mb4`, column `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. **Before that** make sure mysql has a higher version than 5.5.3, you can use navicat to do that
2. modify the mysql configuration file, in windows it's `my.ini`, in linux it's `my.cnf`

   ```
   [client] default-character-set = utf8mb4
   [mysql] default-character-set = utf8mb4 
   [mysqld] character-set-server = utf8mb4
   collation-server = utf8mb4_general_ci
   ```
3. remove `characterEncoding=utf-8` in property file
4. restart mysql server